# When building a docker container I got repository does not exist or may require 'docker login

Tags: docker, mlflow

I am trying to build this container (that months ago worked ok)

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

RUN pip install mlflow

RUN pip install sklearn

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
# Switch back to jovyan to avoid accidental container runs as root
USER $NB_UID
RUN echo $NB_UID
```

However it fails when trying to install mlflow with

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mlflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mlflow
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c pip install mlflow' returned a non-zero code: 1
Unable to find image 'chapter_1_homlflow:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for chapter_1_homlflow, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Has something changed is say jupyter/scipy-notebook? or in mlflow installation method?
How can I make this work?

EDIT: Thanks @Zeitounator for pointing out what was missing.

The error happens when running a script which is `run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
docker build -t chapter_1_homlflow .
docker run --network="host" -p 8888:8888 -p 5000:5000 -p 1235:1235 -v $(pwd):/home/jovyan/ -it --rm chapter_1_homlflow
```

Also I dont know if it is related but I run this on a ubuntu 18 with a pretty old python version (3.6)

EDIT2: Nobody has any solution for this?

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/c0cf88748d65a37dbcebeffd09432776). Note that your output is complaining about an image (`chapter_1_homlflow:latest`) which is not referenced in your Dockerfile nor anywhere else in your question. So you might consider editing your question to make it a [mre]

Comment: Are you on a new network now that requires HTTP proxy settings to be passed in via environment variables?

Comment: @Zeitounator `chapter_1_homlflow:latest` is the tag that `docker build` wants to apply to the image.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning no it is the tag of an image that docker is trying to pull out of dockerhub and we could only guess with the original question that this happens because the build was trying to use the same tag while it failed and that the next command/task was trying to run a container from that image ignoring that the previous build had failed. But we couldn't be sure without a MCVE. Now we are with the edit.

Comment: You should put some error control in your script so that is does not try to run a container from an absent or outdated image in case the build fails. A docker-compose file in place of your script is actually a perfect fit for that. That does not explain why this fail when it shouldn't. As reported by @AlwaysLearning, make sure you're not behind a proxy. And in any case, you should debug access to `https://pypi.org/simple` from a test container to understand why pip access is broken in your environment.